# Does extra data reduce performance in Python objects?

Tags: python

I could probably run experiments to measure this myself, but I'm hoping somebody can provide a detailed answer.

Suppose I have two Python arrays:

```
small_array = [{"x": i, "foo": "hamburger"} for i in range(0,10000)]
big_array = [{"x": i, "foo": "hamburger", "bar": "hotdog"} for i in range(0,10000)]
```

My question is: will basic array operations (such as iteration or accessing by index) that involve only the "x" parameter be faster for `small_array` compared to `big_array`?

I'm asking because I often find myself building a complex data structure X on which I will perform expensive operations A and B such that the overlap between the attributes of X used by A and B is small.  So I'm wondering if there are performance advantages associated with separating X into Y and Z so that A can operate on Y and B can operate on Z.

Comment: By "array", do you mean the outer list or inner dict? Since dict access is hashed into buckets it will mostly only slow down with collisions. Adding a dozen items would likely not make a difference, I suspect.

Comment: Iteration is time-complexity O(n) i.e. grows with the length of the list, predictably.  Accessing by index is O(1) i.e. it should not matter the length of the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The performance difference on reasonably-sized (1000 or fewer items) dicts is statistically insignificant. There may be some degenerate cases where many of the keys hash to the same value but the hash randomization found in modern versions of Python sweeps this under the rug.

As for the list itself, each element is only a reference to another object so the size of the underlying object does not affect list operations.

Answer (score 0):

Iteration and indexing will be the same speed for each of your lists (for future Googling, they are lists, not arrays).